# Distributed Stateful LSTM training using tf.distributed.MirroredStrategy in Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: lstm, distributed, tensorflow2.0, stateful

I am trying to use stateful stacked LSTM layers for training, using tf.distributed.MirroredStrategy, in Tensorflow 2.0. Following is the code generating the required layers.

```
class koopman_aux_net(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self, parameter_list):
        super(koopman_aux_net, self).__init__()
        self.width = parameter_list['kaux_width']
        self.units = parameter_list['kaux_units']
        self.activation = parameter_list['kp_activation']
        self.koopman_layer_real = []
        self.koopman_layer_complex = []
        self.output_units_real = parameter_list['kaux_output_units_real']
        self.output_units_complex = parameter_list['kaux_output_units_complex']
        self.statet = parameter_list['stateful']

    def build(self, input_shape):
        #if self.output_units_real:
        for i in range(self.width):
            self.koopman_layer_real.append(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units= self.units, activation = self.activation, recurrent_activation = 'sigmoid', return_sequences = True, stateful = self.statet))
        self.koopman_layer_real.append(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units= self.output_units_real, activation = self.activation, recurrent_activation = 'sigmoid', return_sequences = True, stateful = self.statet))

        self.real_layers = tf.keras.Sequential(self.koopman_layer_real)

        #if self.output_units_complex:
        for j in range(self.width):
            self.koopman_layer_complex.append(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units= self.units, activation = self.activation, recurrent_activation = 'sigmoid', return_sequences = True, stateful = self.statet))
        self.koopman_layer_complex.append(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units= self.output_units_complex, activation = self.activation, recurrent_activation = 'sigmoid', return_sequences = True, stateful = self.statet))

        self.complex_layers = tf.keras.Sequential(self.koopman_layer_complex)

    def call(self, inputs):

        #print(f'Calling Koopan_aux_net with input shape {inputs.shape}')
        input_real, input_complex = tf.split(inputs, [self.output_units_real, self.output_units_complex], axis= 2)

        x = self.real_layers(input_real)

        y = self.complex_layers(input_complex)

        return tf.concat([x,y], axis=2)
```

I am using the `@tf.function` decorator for the graph generation.

For the above code, I am receiving the following ValueError:

```
    conda-envs/TF2rc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:847 __call__
        outputs = call_fn(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    Koopman_RNN/network_arch.py:100 call  *
        x = self.real_layers(input_real)
    conda-envs/TF2rc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:847 __call__
        outputs = call_fn(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    conda-envs/TF2rc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/sequential.py:270 call
        outputs = layer(inputs, **kwargs)
    conda-envs/TF2rc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/layers/recurrent.py:623 __call__
        return super(RNN, self).__call__(inputs, **kwargs)
    conda-envs/TF2rc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:847 __call__
        outputs = call_fn(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    conda-envs/TF2rc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/layers/recurrent_v2.py:974 call
        updates.append(state_ops.assign(self.states[i], states[i]))
    conda-envs/TF2rc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/state_ops.py:228 assign
        return ref.assign(value, name=name)
    conda-envs/TF2rc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/distribute/values.py:1036 assign
        return self._assign_func(f=assign_fn, *args, **kwargs)
    conda-envs/TF2rc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/distribute/values.py:1016 _assign_func
        variable_type="MirroredVariable"))

    ValueError: You must specify an aggregation method to update a MirroredVariable in 
Replica Context. You can do so by passing an explicit value for argument `aggregation` to tf.Variable(..).e.g. `tf.Variable(..., aggregation=tf.VariableAggregation.SUM)``tf.VariableAggregation` lists the possible aggregation methods.
This is required because MirroredVariable should always be kept in sync. 
When updating them or assigning to them in a replica context, we automatically try to aggregate the values before updating the variable. 
For this aggregation, we need to know the aggregation method. Another alternative is to not try to update such MirroredVariable in replica context, but in cross replica context. You can enter cross replica context by calling `tf.distribute.get_replica_context().merge_call(merge_fn, ..)`.
Inside `merge_fn`, you can then update the MirroredVariable using `tf.distribute.StrategyExtended.update()`.
```

How should I progress about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Tensorflow distributed strategy doesn't support stateful RNN's yet.
[Here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33072#issuecomment-565163224)